# Regex to replace text

Tags: regex

I had this figured out a few months ago, and lost my notes. And my failing memory isn't helping.

Let's say I have a string:

```
Beverly.Hills.Chihuahua.3.Viva.La.Fiesta!.2012.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG]
```

and I want to filter that down to

```
Beverly Hills Chihuahua 3 Viva La Fiesta!
```

What do I need? I need to kill off the last parts, with that year being any 4 digit year, and everything after that being constant.

Comment: From what programming language are you using the regex?

Comment: It's actually going into some software (MetaX), and I can't seem to find anything that shows which is the expected language. It's just a setting in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex :

```
str = Beverly.Hills.Chihuahua.3.Viva.La.Fiesta!.2012.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG]

reg = \(.*\)[[:digit:]]\{4\}\(.*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for is:

```
/.\d\d\d\d.*/g
```

Pattern is:

```
.\d\d\d\d.*
```

In case you are using Javascript, following is regex expression that you can replace with blank:

```
text.match(/.\d\d\d\d.*/g);
```

Use this [link](http://regexr.com/3ddfi) to scrabble with your regex. Just remove the part in replace to get your result.

Comment: But I'm not trying to match the year. I'm trying to remove everything from the dot before the year all the way to the end, and also replace all remaining dots with spaces. But I'm not concerned about that last part.

Comment: This part will get you all the .xxxx* parts which you can replace with blank string. I thought this was the complex part answered.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript I would do it like this:

```js
var str = "Beverly.Hills.Chihuahua.3.Viva.La.Fiesta!.2012.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AG]";
/(.*)\W?\b\d{4}\b/.exec(str).replace(/\./g, ' ')
```

first extract the text, then replace dots by single spaces

<kbd>[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/mA2zN0/1)</kbd>

Comment: I was also thinking on the same lines. But maybe there's an approach where we can capture the strings without `.` in separate groups in one go?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for a one-step solution, but wasn't successful. So I mention here a 2-step process. If anyone can improve it to do it in one step, that would be the perfect solution IMO.

Step 1: Use this `regex`:

```
((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!]*)\.)*?)\d{4}
```

It will capture the string `Beverly.Hills.Chihuahua.3.Viva.La.Fiesta!.` in the first capturing group ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS5kP4/1)).

Step 2: You now need to replace the `.` in `\1` with `space` in order to achieve the desired result.